# What does "go full suburban basics" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What can be meant by "go full suburban basics"?
Jane lives with her fiance in a luxurious gated community. I don't understand if she wants to use the advantage of living in suburban neighbourhood and make food on a grill in backyard, or wants to go somewhere else to grill? I am not sure if I understand this sentence at all :(

> On the way home, I decide to stop at the Whole Foods and pick
> up some groceries. I haven’t cooked a single meal for Eddie since
> we’ve met, and that might be nice. It’s a pretty late spring day, and
> we could go full suburban basics and grill out.

R. Hawkins 'Wife Upstairs"

Comment: The use of *basics* might be related to [the slang meaning "unoriginal, unexceptional, mainstream".](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/basic/)  Everyone grills in the suburbs; it is a very common, expected, unoriginal thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "basic" is meant to be a humorous reference to the military term "basic training". In the military sense, "basic" is the initial unspecialised training that all soldiers take.

And by analogy, cooking on the grill outside is part of "suburban basic training". So she is planning to cook in her own backyard, as this is something everybody in suburbia does.

Comment: interesting perspective of the word "basic"!

Answer (score 0):

In general, "suburban" means "of or characteristic of a suburb", and a suburb means "an outlying district of a city, especially a residential one".

In this context, the text probably wants to say that even though Jane lives in clearly expensive house - "luxurious gated community", Jane probably wants to go back to a so called "lower" level such as a suburb (which is in the middle between the rich and poor in general), and grill out and cook a meal for Eddie, seeing that Jane hasn't cooked a single meal for Eddie before.

"Grill out" in this context probably means grilling somewhere around the house e.g. in the backyard